# Did Starfleet ships get upgrades to use metaphasic shields?

Tags: star-trek

After the success of Dr.Reyga metaphasic shield technology, and the the success (to a certain limit) of Data and La Forge's Metaphasic program for the Enterprise-D as seen in "Descent, Part II", has starfleet pursued this technology to upgrade its fleet shields?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, while the effectiveness of metaphasic shield is not in question there is no information on what the power requirements of such a shield is.  We have only seen it used on a shuttle craft who's shield would have a small surface area, and a ground based installation who's power generating capacity is unknown.  The Enterprise-D did use the Metaphasic Shield program in Descent, Part 2, but there seemed to be a pretty limited time it could function before it used up ship power.

The Enterprise would have it due to Geordi's familiarity with Dr.Reyga's work. But Starfleet may not have implemented it widely unless the power consumption issue could be solved.  Though it may only be used in specialty projects.